# go run uses stale versions of sub-packages

Tags: go

I'm trying out the [Jaeger/OpenTracing tutorial](https://medium.com/opentracing/take-opentracing-for-a-hotrod-ride-f6e3141f7941) and finding that none of my changes to the HotROD application code have any effect.

The project structure is something like (abridged):

```
├── main.go
├── pkg
└── services
    ├── config
    │   └── config.go
    ├── customer
    ├── driver
    ├── frontend
    └── route
```

I start the application by running `go run main.go all`.
It behaves as expected, the traces on Jaeger all match the screenshots on Medium.

I edit `services/config/config.go` to change the RouteWorkerPoolSize and MySQLGetDelay variables as directed.
Then stop the server and start it again with `go run main.go all`

I'd expect these changes to be reflected in the newly running server, but they aren't. The behaviour is the exact same as before. It's like go is running the old code.

Am I misunderstanding something about `go run`?

Environment variables:

```
GOPATH="/home/ronnie/go"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
```

working directory:

```
/home/ronnie/go/src/github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/examples/hotrod
```

Go version 1.12.6 running on Kubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

[`go run`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program) compiles and runs the named main Go package.

Only [`go build`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies) or [`go install`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies) would compile the packages named by the import paths, along with their dependencies,